# Azure stream analytics join on datediff not working as expected

Tags: azure, join, stream, analytics, datediff

I have 2 event hubs which are receiving data. I want to link both in Azure stream analytics based upon their timestamps. One of the streams has a delay of up to 12 minutes compared to the other one.

```
SELECT
    I1.endtime,
    I1.value,
    I1.id,
    I2.lat,
    I2.lon,
    I2.t,
    DATEDIFF(second,I1.endtime, I2.t) as sec_diff
INTO
    output
FROM
    locationinput I2 TIMESTAMP BY t 
    JOIN sensorinput I1 TIMESTAMP BY endtime 
ON DATEDIFF(second, I1, I2) between 0 and 59
```

The datediff does not seem to take into account the TIMESTAMP BY (so difference between t & endtime) - this is one of the output records I get.

```
endtime : 2018-07-24T14:44:00.0000000Z
value : 4
id : 2536
lat : 50
lon : 4
t : 2018-07-24T14:56:05.1440000Z
sec_diff : 725
```

How can the diff_sec value even be higher than 59 ?

Comment: It seems to work though when I use the timestamps added by Azure (e.g. EventEnqueuedUTCTime). So it could be related to incorrect intepretation of timestamps, although they look exactly the same.